# count how many times the column a values are between two numbers and column b values are bigger than other number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, dataset

i have the following dataframe With the two columns A and B

```
A  B     
1  1
2  2
3  5 
46 4
52 5
2  4
3  4
```

I want to find how many times column values in A are bigger than 20 and smaller than 30 and in B how many times column values are bigger than 10

Comment: did you mean greater than 20 and smaller than 30? What you phrased is impossible (so always False)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df['A'].between(20, 30).sum(), df['B'].gt(10).sum()
```

output: `(0, 0)`

Comment: i applied your method to my real dataframe

Comment: count15_30 = frames['dif'].between(15,30).sum(), frames['ratio'].gt(0.05).sum()

Comment: the output is 
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: do you know what went wrong ?

Comment: No I don't, can you provide a reproducible example that triggers the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
>>> sum(df['A'].between(20, 30) & df['B'].gt(10))
0
```